# What Does the IsMajorVersion Field on the ContentVersion Object Do?

Tags: files, contentversion, boolean

I referred to this **[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)**.  The description for `IsMajorVersion` is:

> "*true* if the document is a major version; *false* if the document is a minor version. **Major versions can’t be replaced**."

What exactly is implied by "Major versions can’t be replaced"?

I have a file in Salesforce with `IsMajorVersion` true, inserted by this code:

```
public static void insertUpdatedDocument(List<ContentDocumentLink> documentLinks, Map<String, Blob> docData)
{
    List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink documentLink : documentLinks) 
    {
        String documentId = documentLink.ContentDocumentId;
        String documentName = documentLink.ContentDocument.title;
        String documentType = documentLink.ContentDocument.FileExtension;
        Blob versionData = docData.get(documentId);
        
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
        cv.ContentDocumentId = documentId;
        cv.VersionData =  versionData;
        cv.Title = documentName+'.'+documentType;
        cv.PathOnClient = cv.Title;
        cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
        cv.OwnerId = Label.Remote_Trx_DocumentOwnerId ;               
        contentVersions.add(cv);
    }
    
    insert contentVersions;
}
```

But I *can* upload a new version via the UI:

[image]

So what is that field really supposed to prevent?

Comment: I think it is meant to prevent overwrites. It is forcing users to create new version instead of overwriting same version with new content.